# Up Down counter code

Tags: verilog

I need help in my project which is a counter that counts up or down from 0 to 20. I already did my counter code and it's working in active HDL. But now I need to show the numbers in 7-segment in `nexys 3` FPGA board.

I have the code of the segment, but I have a problem when I call the module of segment - it is giving me an error in active HDL. Can you please tell me what is the error?

This is my current code :

```
module main
    #(parameter N=7)
    (
    input switch,
    input button,
    input fastclk,
    output [3:0] enable,
    output reg[6:0] out
    );    
    wire[N:0]count;
    wire slowclk;

    clock c1(fastclk,slowclk);
    Updown u1(switch,button,slowclk,count);
    segment s1([3:0]count,[7:4]count,fastclk,enable,out); 
    endmodule


module clock(fastclk,slowclk); //clock code
    input fastclk;
    output wire slowclk;
    reg[25:0]period_count = 0;

    always @(posedge fastclk)
        begin
            period_count <= period_count + 1;
        end
    assign slowclk = period_count[25];
endmodule

module Updown // UpDown Counter
#(parameter N=7)    
    (
    input switch,
    input button,
    input clk,
    output reg [N:0]count=8'd0,
    );  


always @(posedge clk)
    begin

        if(switch == 1 && button == 1)  // Countup from 0 to 20
            begin 
                if(count == 8'd20)
                    count <= 0 ;

                else 
                    count <= count +1;

            end
        else if(switch == 0 && button == 1) // Countdown from 20 to 0
        begin 
                if(count == 8'd0)
                    count <= 8'd20 ;

                else 
                    count <= count -1;

            end 
        else count <=8'd0;  
    end
endmodule

module mux(A,B,sel,Y); // 2x1 Multiplexer
    input [3:0]A;
    input [3:0]B;
    input sel;
    output [3:0]Y;
    reg [3:0]Y;

    always @(*)
        begin 
            if(sel==0)
                Y=A;
            else 
                Y=B;

            end
endmodule

module hex7seg(input wire [3:0]x , output reg[6:0]a_to_g); // Hex to 7seg Code

    always @(*)

        case(x)
            0: a_to_g = 7'b0000001; 
            1: a_to_g = 7'b1001111;
            2: a_to_g = 7'b0010010;
            3: a_to_g = 7'b0000110;
            4: a_to_g = 7'b1001100;
            5: a_to_g = 7'b0100100;
            6: a_to_g = 7'b0100000;
            7: a_to_g = 7'b0001111;
            8: a_to_g = 7'b0000000;
            9: a_to_g = 7'b0000100;
            'hA: a_to_g = 7'b0001000;
            'hB: a_to_g = 7'b1100000;
            'hC: a_to_g = 7'b0110001;
            'hD: a_to_g = 7'b1000010;
            'hE: a_to_g = 7'b0110000;
            'hF: a_to_g = 7'b0111000;
            default: a_to_g = 7'b0000001;
        endcase
endmodule

module segment (a,b,fast,enable,seg7);
    input [3:0]a;
    input [3:0]b;
    input fast;
    output [3:0] enable;
    output [6:0] seg7;
    wire [3:0]e1 = 4'b1110;
    wire [3:0]e2 = 4'b1101;
    wire slow;
    wire [3:0]number;

    clock c1(fast,slow);
    mux m1(a,b,slow,number);
    mux m2(e1,e2,slow,enable);
    hex7seg h1(number,seg7);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a small error in `segment` module initialization part of code:

```
segment s1([3:0]count,[7:4]count,fastclk,enable,out);
```

This part of code should look a little bit different:

```
segment s1(count[3:0],count[7:4],fastclk,enable,out);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The big issue is:

   ```
   segment s1([3:0]count,[7:4]count,fastclk,enable,out);
   ```

   It should be:

   ```
   segment s1(count[3:0],count[7:4],fastclk,enable,out);
   ```

   Other option *(IEEE Std 1364-2001 auto connect by name (`.*`))*:

   ```
   segment s1(.a(count[3:0]), .b(count[7:4]), .fast(fastclk), .seg7(out), .*);
   ```
2. Some simulators may complain about initial values on outputs with ANSI style port lists or trailing comma in the port list. So this:

   ```
   output reg [N:0]count=8'd0,
   );
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
   output reg [N:0] count
   );
   initial count=8'd0;
   ```

   I prefer being able to control the reset in my designs, so I'd prefer:

   ```
   input reset_n,
   output reg [N:0] count
   );
   always @(posedge clk
     // or negedge reset_n // <-- uncomment for asynchronous reset
     ) begin
     if (!reset_n) begin
       count=8'd0;
     end
     else begin
       // synchronous code here
     end
   end
   ```
3. In `main` you have `output reg[6:0] out`. Since out is not assigned by an always-block in `main` (sub-modules don't count), it should be a `wire` not a `reg`. This one is a guideline as it is best practice for Verilog, most simulates tolerate it.